# Finding the paper "Polynomial Inequalities" by Borislav Bojanov

Tags: polynomials, paper-request

I'm looking for the paper

> B. D. Bojanov, *Polynomial inequalities*, in “Open Problems in Approximation Theory” (B. Bojanov, Ed.), pp. 25–42, SCT, Singapore, 1993.

The above reference is taken from the article: G. Milovanović, T. M. Rassias, *New developments on Turán's extremal problems for polynomials* (English summary), [MR1625242](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=1625242) on Mathscinet. I cannot find the article or the proceedings (Open Problems in Approximation Theory), where it was published, on Mathscinet, zbMath, WorldCat or anywhere online (I can't even find a website for the publishing company).

Does anyone have a copy or know how to get a copy of the article? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Other places online list the citation for the proceedings slightly differently as "CST Publishing, Singapore, 1994" but that hasn't helped me find it online.

Comment: Did you try to use a library or interlibrary loan by any chance?

Comment: @RW I can't find a library that has a copy of the proceedings. I tried WorldCat but it comes up with no library suggestions. Do you by any chance know of one?

Comment: The keyword to use in your library is "interlibrary loan". It is interlibrary loan desk's task to find it for you.

Comment: Indeed, for some reason it is not listed by MathSciNet and by ZbМath. The only record I could locate online is in this list from the Bulgarian National Library, see item 998 on p.214 of https://www.nationallibrary.bg/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Bulgarika_2004-2005.pdf . Unfortunately, the ISBN number given there is apparently wrong, and it is not clear whether the library actually has it.